# How to get the best matched result with The Google Geocoding API

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

there is any way to get a single, best matched element from this url:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Lipinki&sensor=false&components=country:PL

I have to get a single element for results for Poland. I would to get the same result which i can see on maps.google.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do it. Google will send you a list of possible matches and you have to use it. Generally first one is the closest one but no guarantees there. Best way is to show multiple spots on map or just use the first one. If you want exact match your address=Lipinki should contain full address (street address).

Regarding your second question, yes you will get same location you see in google maps search. Look at the geo points they are pretty close.